# InitializeComponent() - Ambiguous invocation warning?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper, mef

I admit that I'm new to the world of `xaml` but seeing warnings using the built-in Visual Studio templates indicate that there might be another issue *besides my brain*.

If I create an empty `VSIX Project` (**it has to be a VSIX Project**) in Visual Studio using `Add -> New Project`, and then proceed to create a new user control using  `Add -> New Item -> User Control (WPF)`, after I have compiled the code, the editor shows me the warning `Ambiguous invocation` on the line `InitializeComponent()`, as shown below:

[image: ambiguous invocation]

---

#### EDIT

There are warnings in the Designer view as well, shown below:

[image: designer view]

---

The warning is only present in the editor. Building the project is no problem, as shown below:

[image]

---

**Please note** that there are **NO** warnings if you add a `User Control (WPF)` to a `Class Library (.NET Framework)` project, as shown below:

[image]

---

If I look in the `obj/Debug/` folder of `SomeProject` I see two files for `SomeControl`. The first is `SomeControl.g.cs`, and the second is `SomeControl.g.i.cs`. The files are identical.

The same goes for the `obj/Debug/` folder of `SomeOtherProject`, without the warning.

I have cloned various official Microsoft repos (e.g. [UnitTestBoilerplateGenerator](https://github.com/Microsoft/UnitTestBoilerplateGenerator/)) and the warning is present here as well, for example in: [src/View/CreateUnitTestBoilerplateDialog.xaml.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/UnitTestBoilerplateGenerator/blob/master/src/View/CreateUnitTestBoilerplateDialog.xaml.cs) at `InitializeComponent()`, as shown below:

[image: microsoft project]

---

What's going on?? =(

#### EDIT

This is using **Visual Studio 15.4** and **ReSharper 2017.2.2**; I don't seem to be getting this warning with older versions of Visual Studio/ReSharper.

#### EDIT

This seem to be a ReSharper specific problem, since after suspending ReSharper the warnings are no longer present. I have submitted a bug through `ReSharper -> Help -> Report a Bug or Submit Feedback...`.

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to tell them about it.

Comment: I have submitted a bug to ReSharper. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [a known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-466713) for ReSharper 2017.2.x

Update: It was fixed in ReSharper 2017.3 version.

Comment: I'm on 2017.3.3 and it's definitively not solved :-(

Comment: I have 2017.3.5 and it's not fixed in this version.

Comment: It will be fixed in 2018.1 EAP based on the comments in the issue.